# PHP Post Values undefined

Tags: php, post

when i am trying to get my POST values from my php class, it always return **"Undefined variable"**

But how it can be undefined i really did not getting it!!!

This is my **POST** data

[image]

This is my **Response** data

[image]

This is my PHP code --

```
class sendMailController extends Controller {

        protected function init() {
        $this->saveDataAction();
    }

    public function saveDataAction() {
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=='POST'){
            $_POST['name'] = $name;
            $_POST['email'] = $email;
            $_POST['message'] = $msg;
            print_r($name);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my script ---

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myForm").on('submit', function (e) {
            var data = {};
            data['name'] = $("#name").val();
            data['email'] = $("#email").val();
            data['message'] = $("#message").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/mvc/sendmail',
                type: 'post',
                data: data,
                success: function (returnedData) {

                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Do any one knows where i am making the mistake !!!
Please really need some advice

Comment: This does not make sense: `$_POST['name'] = $name`. You assign the value of the undefined variable `$name` to the element `$_POST['name']`. Assignments are always right value into left variable, in all programming languages. You probably want to turn that around, I guess: `$name = $_POST['name'];`

Comment: `$name = $_POST['name'];` etc

Comment: Can you post the actual response instead of images? That will make it easier for all of us to help you out.

Comment: thanks a lot everyone ...

Answer (score 4):

You are doing reverse assignment, Here is correct

```
class sendMailController extends Controller {

        protected function init() {
        $this->saveDataAction();
    }

    public function saveDataAction() {
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=='POST'){
            $name = $_POST['name'] ;
            $email = $_POST['email'] ;
            $msg = $_POST['message'] ;
            print_r($name);
        }
    }
}
```

This is wrong: `$_POST['name'] = $name`. You assign the value of the **undefined variable** `$name` to the post element `$_POST['name']`. **Assignments are always right value into left variable, in all programming languages.** You need to reverse it like: `$name = $_POST['name']`;

Answer (score 0):

I believe instead of using **"$_POST"** try to use like so ---

```
class sendMailController extends Controller {

        protected function init() {
        $this->saveDataAction();
    }

    public function saveDataAction() {
        $request = $this->getRequest();

           if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

            $name = $request->request->get('name');
            $email = $request->request->get('email');
            $message = $request->request->get('message');
        }
    }
}
```

I believe this is a better practise for getting the POST values